# Decimals in gnuplot labels

Tags: gnuplot

I'm tryig to make a label with a decimal number, my code is this:

```
set terminal png
set yrange[0.455:0.51]
a=0
do for [t=2:10]{a=a+0.23;set label "t(s)=".a at 85,0.505; set output "t".t.".png"; plot "explicit.txt" u 1:t notitle;unset label}
```

When I try to plot it, Gnuplot says:STRING operator applied to undefined or non-STRING variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways. I would use a sprintf statement:

```
set label sprintf("t(s)=%.3f",a)
set output sprintf("t%d.png", t)
```